# Java ExecutorService Runnable doesn't update value

Tags: java, concurrency, runnable, executorservice, java.util.concurrent

I'm using Java to download HTML contents of websites whose URLs are stored in a database. I'd like to put their HTML into database, too. 
I'm using `Jsoup` for this purpose:

```
public String downloadHTML(String byLink) {
        String htmlInPage = "";
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(byLink).get();
            htmlInPage = doc.html();
        } catch (org.jsoup.UnsupportedMimeTypeException e) {
            // process this and some other exceptions
        } 
        return htmlInPage;
    }
```

I'd like to download websites concurrently and use this function:

```
public void downloadURL(int websiteId, String url, 
                        String categoryName, ExecutorService executorService) {
   executorService.submit((Runnable) () -> {
       String htmlInPage = downloadHTML(url);
       System.out.println("Category: " + categoryName + " " + websiteId + " " + url);
       String insertQuery = 
              "INSERT INTO html_data (website_id, html_contents)  VALUES (?,?)";
       dbUtils.query(insertQuery, websiteId, htmlInPage);   
   });
}
```

dbUtils is my class based on Apache Commons DbUtils. Details are here: http://pastebin.com/iAKXchbQ 
And I'm using everything mentioned above in a such way: (`List<Object[]>`  details are explained on pastebin, too)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        DbUtils dbUtils = new DbUtils("host", "db", "driver", "user", "pass");
        List<String> categoriesList = 
                     Arrays.asList("weapons", "planes", "cooking", "manga");
        String sql = "SELECT lw.id, lw.website_url, category_name " +
                "FROM list_of_websites AS lw JOIN list_of_categories AS lc " +
                "ON lw.category_id = lc.id " +
                "where category_name = ? ";

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        for (String category : categoriesList) {
            List<Object[]> sitesInCategory = dbUtils.select(sql, category );
            for (Object[] entry : sitesInCategory) {
                int websiteId = (int) entry[0];
                String url = (String) entry[1];
                String categoryName = (String) entry[2];
                downloadURL(websiteId, url, categoryName, executorService);
            }
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
}
```

I'm not sure if this solution is correct but it works. Now I want to modify code to save HTML not from all websites in my database, but only their fixed ammount in each category. 
 
For example, download and save HTML of 50 websites from the "weapons" category, 50 from "planes", etc. I don't think it's necessary to use sql for this purpose: if we select 50 sites per category, it doesn't mean we save them all, because of possibly incorrect syntax and connection problems. 
I've tryed to create separate class implementing `Runnable` with fields: `counter` and `maxWebsitesPerCategory`, but these variables aren't updated. Another idea was to create field `Map<String,Integer> sitesInCategory` instead of `counter`, put each category as a key there and increment its value until it reaches `maxWebsitesPerCategory`, but it didn't work, too. Please, help me! 

P.S: I'll also be grateful for any recommendations connected with my realization of concurrent downloading (I haven't worked with concurrency in Java before and this is my first attempt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
for (String category : categoriesList) {
        dbUtils.select(sql, category).stream()
            .limit(50)
            .forEach(entry -> {
                int websiteId = (int) entry[0];
                String url = (String) entry[1];
                String categoryName = (String) entry[2];
                downloadURL(websiteId, url, categoryName, executorService);
            });
    }
```

`sitesInCategory` has been replaced with a stream of at most 50 elements, then your code is run on each entry.

#### EDIT

In regard to comments. I've gone ahead and restructured a bit, you can modify/implement the content of the methods I've suggested.

```
public void werk(Queue<Object[]> q, ExecutorService executorService) {
    executorService.submit(() -> {
        try {
            Object[] o = q.remove();
            try {
                String html = downloadHTML(o); // this takes one of your object arrays and returns the text of an html page

                insertIntoDB(html); // this is the code in the latter half of your downloadURL method
            }catch (/*narrow exception type indicating download failure*/Exception e) {
                werk(q, executorService);
            }
        }catch (NoSuchElementException e) {}
    });
}
```

^^^ This method does most of the work.

```
for (String category : categoriesList) {
    Queue<Object[]> q = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>(dbUtils.select(sql, category));
    IntStream.range(0, 50).forEach(i -> werk(q, executorService));
}
```

^^^ this is the `for` loop in your main

Now each category tries to download 50 pages, upon failure of downloading a page it moves on and tries to download another page. In this way, you will either download 50 pages or have attempted to download all pages in the category.

Comment: Very nice solution! It really gets from list no more than 50 entries per category. But `downloadURL` saves less than 50 websites in each category due to invalid URL syntax or connection problems. Is it possible to download exactly 50 for each category, despite this problems? Maybe, we should insert counter inside `Runnable` and update its value? The difficulty is that the process is asynchronous, and the categories aren't processed one-by-one. In fact, downloading process looks like mixture: website from "planes", from "weapons", from "cooking", from "weapons", from "cooking", etc

Comment: So it's best to fix the url syntax problems by ensuring that whatever you're putting in the database is a valid url, before you put it in. Are your connection problems stemming from your end, or the fact that the server the URL points to potentially no longer exists? Because if it's just your connection we can build exception handling to retry until we succeed, but if you're not sure the server is still there on the other end then we can do something else.

Comment: Okay, I'll make syntax correct, but what about connection problems? They are not at my side, they are caused by the remote servers (404-error, 403, 503, etc). Broadly speaking, what I am doing: 1)download categorized list of websites, e.g: http://www.shallalist.de/  2)put them into database, 3)download HTML contents by categories (e.g, 1000 of wensites per category - the ammount is desirable to be equal), 4)extract text from HTML-source, text from tags: <title> and <meta>, calculate HTML-tags' frequency. These features are used for Data Mining with RapidMiner.

Comment: I agree with your idea: it seems to be clear and efficient. I tryed to modify this code a little and launch it...Sorry to disturb you, but the number of the websites is still less than 50:( I don't think it's connected with the little ammount of sites in categories (619 in weapons, 687 in planes, etc). But where can be the problem? If you have some time, could you please look at the whole code? It's here: http://pastebin.com/Cs8MZRqM and http://pastebin.com/ZFCj0tmm

Comment: @Tofrar well a quick suggestion before I look at the rest, don't shut down the executor service at the end of main. Shutting it down will wait for current tasks to complete, but won't take any more. So if a download fails it won't be able to attempt the next site in the q. Also, it doesn't look like you're making use of the catch on line 72 in werk. Your else blocks on 59 and 69 should throw new DownloadMessedUpException or something.

Comment: I decided to throw new Exception() and used another your recommendation not to shutdown ExecutorService. Wow, it's working!:) Fantastic! Thank you! But how to make the program finish correctly? Now I have 50-50-50-50, but it hangs...

Comment: @Tofrar <mumble>something Callables something Futures of Futures of Futures... </mumble>

Comment: Okay, I'll try. Thank you!)

Comment: @Tofrar let me know if you can't figure it out, I'll write an example.

Comment: Could you do it, please? I've tryed, but no result and it's difficult for me:(

Comment: @Tofrar just have werk return a Future. If the download succeeds, the future can be of a null, if not it can be the return from the resulting backup call to werk. Just redeem all your futures, if a future is null, go on to the next future in the list, if not then wait to redeem the redeemed future. I'll try to write up an example when I have time, maybe Friday?

Comment: Smth like this? But I'm completely unsure. http://pastebin.com/8igZav2F It finishes correctly but seems that the ammount per category is less than 50 again.. I'd better try to wait untill you have some time

Comment: @Tofrar http://pastebin.com/0gRS6kDG You need to get all possible futures of futures.

Comment: Hmmm...it's strange: it finishes but the ammount is less than `sitesPerCategory`. I tryed to add to that code not only `executorService.shutdown();` but also `executorService.awaitTermination(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES);` to give the tasks time to fininsh. However, I'm not sure if this solution is correct in general, for different values of `sitesPerCategory`